# Fredholm Alternative - what went wrong?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, orthogonality, homogeneous-equation

So I found the general solution for this DE with these BCs:
$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+u=1$$
$$u(0)=u(L)=0$$
by doing:
$$u(x)=Acos(x)+Bsin(x)+1$$
$$u(0)=0=A+1 \therefore A=-1$$
$$u(L)=0=-cos(L)+Bsin(L)+1 \therefore B=\frac{cos(L)-1}{sin(L)}$$
$$\implies u(x)=-cos(x)+1+sin(x)\frac{cos(L)-1}{sin(L)}=1-cos(x)-sin(x)tan(\frac{L}{2})$$

So then I wanted to check the Fredholm Alternative. So the homogeneous solution would be:
$$u_h(x)=Acos(x)+Bsin(x)$$
$$u_h(0)=0=A \therefore A=0$$
$$u_h(L)=0=Bsin(L) \implies L=n\pi \implies B=1$$
$$\implies u_h(x)=sin(x)$$
so checking Fredholm...
$$\int_{0}^{L} (1)sin(x) dx=-cos(x)\Big|_0^L=1-cos(L)\ne0$$

Could anyone give me insight what's going on here? Doesn't this mean that the Fredholm Alternative is telling me there's no solution? What's going on here? Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

**edit:**

The Fredholm alternative summarizes the results for nonhomogeneous problems:
$$L(u)=f(x)$$
subject to homogeneous BCs of the self-adjoint type. Either:

- $u=0$ is the only homogeneous solution (i.e. $\lambda \ne 0$) in which case the nonhomogeneous problem has a unqiue solutions, or
- there are nontrivial homogeneous solutions $\phi_h(x)$ (i.e. $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue) in which case the nonhomogeneous problem has no solutions or an infinite number of solutions

For the nonhomogeneous problem with homogeneous BCs, then, solutions exist only if the forcing function is orthogonal to all homogeneous solutions.

The forcing function being orthogonal to the homogeneous solution (with weight 1) is represented by:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x) \phi_h(x) dx=0$$

The number of solutions of $L(u)=f(x)$ subject to homogeneous BCs is given by:

- if $\phi_h=0$ ($\lambda\ne0$) and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x) \phi_h(x) dx=0$ then the number of solutions is $=1$
- if $\phi_h\ne0$ ($\lambda=0$) and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x) \phi_h(x) dx=0$ then the number of solutions is $=\infty$
- if $\phi_h\ne0$ ($\lambda=0$) and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x) \phi_h(x) dx\ne0$ then the number of solutions is $=0$

Comment: Do you mind stating the "Fredholm Alternative" you have in mind?

Comment: @mickep I just edited op to add info about that, let me know if that helps.

Comment: The point is that sometimes the second bullet of your formulation of the Fredholm alternative actually *does* apply, because some BCs make $0$ into an eigenvalue of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + I$. In these cases your solution attempt in the second block of equations turns out to make no sense because it involves a division by zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do your first solution, you have to be a bit careful. If $L=n\pi$ with $n\in\mathbb Z$ you cannot divide by $\sin(L)$ since it is zero.

If $L\neq n\pi$ with $n\in\mathbb Z$ you have exactly one solution.

If $L=2n\pi$ you have $\cos(L)=1$ so the second boundary condition is satisfied, and there will be infinitely many solutions,
$$
u(x)=1-\cos x+B\sin x.
$$

If $L=(2n-1)\pi$ you have $\cos(L)=-1$, so the second boundary condition is not satisfied. Thus, no solutions.

I suggest that you try to fit this into the theory of Fredholm alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply! Since I have (cos(L)-1)/sin(L), if L=n*pi, I'll be dividing by 0... which is a problem. With L=(2n-1)pi, the BCs are not satisfied, meaning no solutions, and Fredholm is 0, so no solutions there. Thanks a lot, this was helpful.

Comment: follow up question: if L=n x pi, does that mean u=1-cos(x), since I can't divide by sin(L)? **edit:** or does this mean it's not possible to find a general solution when L=n x pi?

Comment: I divided the cases of multiples of $\pi$ in two cases; odd ones and even ones. Since you accepted the answer, I guess everything is fine now?